# Googlesheets Importdata from onedrive

Tags: google-sheets, onedrive

I used to import a spreadsheet from dropbox's public folder into a google spreadsheet
But Dropbox stop the public folder service so I tried alternative with Onedrive.
But the very same spreadsheet won't import in google spreadsheet

dropbox version

```
=importdata ("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2010525/xxx111.CSV")
```

one drive version

```
=importdata ("https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjKRI20GRDHHgzT07aBpOYmesNmO")
```

[example google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WflkC1RHsQ_Z4rRmVz6LikxFy0GufyqQrLwMa9WK4vY/edit?usp=sharing)

Anyone know what is going wrong here?

[csv file on dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2010525/xxx111.CSV)

[Same cvs file on OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjKRI20GRDHHgzT07aBpOYmesNmO)

Answer (score 0):

2 things I notice right away :

That file is a shortened URL that triggers the download, and so that is not the actual file source... but the dropbox one is, which you can also tell by the fact that the URL ends in `.CSV`

In order for it to work, you need to be passing it the actual file, not a redirecting URL.

Second the details still say not shared even though its public enough to let anyone download...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with OneDrive, but you can still use DropBox to achieve the desired result.

When generating a public link to a file in Dropbox, Dropbox by default passes a link to a document embedded in an HTML frame that looks kind of like this (Caveat, this is *not* a real document):

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/abc123abc123/cfl.dropboxstatic.com.url?dl=0
```

By changing the query of the `dl` tag from `0` to `1` in the URL, you can [force the file to download](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/201).  Change the terminal `0` to `1` in the Dropbox-generated URL, and you should be able to import the data using Google's IMPORTDATA().